# Flutter search from model provider

Tags: flutter, dart

After a few days it didn't work, I combined the data on the model initially
example: Samsung has a lot of data and I have combined it into an array, I want to ask how to make a search based on the brand name of the model?

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    remoteModelId.clear();
    isLoading = true;
    final products = Provider.of<List<Brands>>(context);
    return Scaffold(
        ...
        body: products != null
            ? ListView.separated(
                itemCount: products.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  
                  var lol = [];
                  var idModel = [];
                  var sublist = [].join();
                  var countList =[];
                  //var allList =[];
                 
                  //var subLol = lol.indexOf(lol);
                  for(var ok in products){
                    lol.add(ok.brandName);
                    idModel.add(ok.ids);
                     countList.add(lol);
                    if(lol.contains(lol)){
                      sublist.compareTo(lol[index]);
                      break;
                    }
                    
                  }
                  distinctIds = lol.toSet().toList();
                  hasilakhir = Set.of(distinctIds).toList();
                  newDataList = List.from(distinctIds);
                  templist.add(hasilakhir);
                  
                  final myMap = Map();
                  
                  lol.forEach((element) { 
                    if(!myMap.containsKey(element)){
                      myMap[element] = 1;
                      return false;
                    }else{
                      myMap[element] += 1;
                      return false;
                    }
                  });
                  //newDataList = newDataList.map((brand)=>brand.toLowerCase()).toList();                
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(hasilakhir[index]),
```

Thanks

Comment: I am sorry but I do not understand what you are asking. What list in your code do you want to 'search', and what do you want to do with the results?

Comment: The test `if(lol.contains(lol))` will never succeed :)

Comment: Sorry for the explanation that is difficult to understand, I mean ignoring the code after itemBuilder arrives at the listTile, what I asked about was the function to search data based on the model name brand

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you need, but here is some example code:

```
  // Get products with a specific brandName
  print(
      'Number of Samsung=${products.where((p) => p.brandName == 'Samsung').length}');

  // Count products by brandName - like your code
  final map = Map();
  products.forEach((product) {
    if (!map.containsKey(product.brandName)) {
      map[product.brandName] = 1;
    } else {
      map[product.brandName] += 1;
    }
  });
  print('map=$map');
  
  // Group products by brandName, with the count and list of ids
  final map2 = Map();
  products.forEach((product) {
    if (!map2.containsKey(product.brandName)) {
      map2[product.brandName] = {
        'count': 1,
        'ids': [product.ids]
      };
    } else {
      var current = map2[product.brandName];
      current['count']++;
      current['ids'].add(product.ids);
    }
  });
  print('map2=$map2');
```

The output with my test data is:

```
Number of Samsung=3
map={Samsung: 3, Apple: 3}
map2={Samsung: {count: 3, ids: [S1, S2, S3]}, Apple: {count: 3, ids: [iPhone1, iPhone2, iPhone3]}}
```

I do not know if it is helpful, but I have annotated some of your code below:

```
  // Get list of distinct brandNames
  var distinctIds = lol.toSet().toList();
  // Get list of distinct brandNames - same as distinctIds
  var hasilakhir = Set.of(distinctIds).toList();
  // Copy list distinctIds
  var newDataList = List.from(distinctIds);
  List templist = [];
  // Make a list with one element which is the list of brandNames
  templist.add(hasilakhir);
```

Comment: thanks for your attention, il'l try you code solution